# cJSON.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, json, linux, cjson

I had too many problems with compiling different libraries for json and finally I got an already compiled library of json which is cJSON to be linked with my project but when I downloaded it, and linked it with a test c file like:

```
//file1.c    
 #include "cJSON.h"
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

then I compiled it through gcc using command:

```
gcc file1.c -lcJSON
```

it returns:

```
file1.c:7:19: fatal error: cJSON.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cJSON.h"
```

Comment: Where did you install the `cJSON.h` header file? You may need to pass `-I/dir/in/which/header/is/located` to the compiler.

Comment: @FUZxxl well, I couldn't find the "cJSON.h" header file that been created by the installation process so I pass the directory of "cJSON.h" header file that I have placed it in the home folder then I got this error:  `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcJSON` , since I've no big experience with linux could you explain this please?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally after several tries I succeed to figure out the problem and fix it. since cJSON is a static library so I can not perform dynamic linking like: `-lcJSON`, the perfect way to compile file1.c and link cJSON lib to it, is by:

1. Add cJSON.c and cJSON.h files to the same directory of file1.c.
2. Include "cJSON.h" in file1.c .
3. execute the command `gcc cJSON.c file1.c -lm`.

Finally compilation success.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is a good solution and may mislead people who view it. Pulling source directly into your project means that you no longer get improvements and bug fixes.

Answer (score 2):

You can also install the cJSON library package if you are compiling it on a Ubuntu machine:

sudo apt install libcjson1 libcjson-dev

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know where to find the include file so you have to tell it where to look (as Fuz suggested). Assuming you installed it as a package on a linux system, it will likely be somewhere like this `/usr/include/cjson/cJSON.h` (to find it you can use something like `find /usr -iname cjson.h`). So based on where it was installed on my machine, add `-I/usr/include/` to the compiler command line and use `#include <cjson/cJSON.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

the correct path to the header library is `#include <cjson/cJSON.h>` when installed using the default Makefile configurations.

Also, the compilation command is incorrect, the cJSON library is installed under `cjson` in all lowercase. Therefore, use `gcc file1.c -lcjson` and it will work.

As @Zainab said, the double quotes `"` that surround the file name are when the header file is located **inside the same directory as the file you are compiling**. The less/greater than symbols `<>` are to specify an installed library on the system.

To list installed libraries on your system (assuming you're on a *NIX system, you may run `ldconfig -p`). when grepping it with `ldconfig -p | grep 'cJSON'` nothing returns on my side, whereas grepping with `cjson` does return results:

```
        libcjson_utils.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libcjson_utils.so.1
        libcjson_utils.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libcjson_utils.so
        libcjson.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libcjson.so.1
        libcjson.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libcjson.so
```

Even more ironically, using the `cjson/cjson.h` header file **does not work**, whereas `cjson/cJSON.h` does indeed work.

Answer (score -1):

this works for me,

```
#include "cJSON.h"
#include "cJSON.c"
```

I downloaded source code from https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON

I am using this code for visual studio

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 0

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "cJSON.h"
#include "cJSON.c"

char* cJSON_GetObjectCstr(cJSON* object, const char* name) {
    const cJSON* item = cJSON_GetObjectItem(object, name);
    return cJSON_GetStringValue(item);
}
int main() {
    cJSON* params = NULL;
    params = cJSON_CreateObject();
    cJSON_AddStringToObject(params, "id", "10");
    cout << cJSON_GetObjectCstr(params, "id") << endl;
    cJSON_Delete(params);
}
```